# Laravel collective select list with default selected value

Tags: laravel, list, select

I try to populate Laravel forms select list with some data and default selected value like this

```
 @foreach($pesron->state as $state)  
    {{ Form::select('state[]', \App\City::pluck('Description', 'id'), $state->city->Description,['class' => 'form-control'])!!} 
 @endforeach
```

I want `$state->city->Description` value will be selected by default in select list. Is it possible? I use 5.7.15 version

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using Laravel Collective's form helpers.

Take a look here https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html#drop-down-lists

```
echo Form::select('size', ['L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small'], 'S');
```

Comment: Kevin Jung, thank you for your answer. I try to do  {{ Form::select('state[]', ['L'=>'Large','S'=>$state->city->Description],'S' }}  ,$state->city->Description  selected by default, and when I want to catch dd($request->all()) state[] returns 'S' ,not $state->city->Description value

Comment: The easy solution wold be to just use `$state->city->Description` as the key as well for the selection array.

Comment: You mean {{ Form::select('state[]', ['L'=>'Large',$state->city->Description=>$state->city->Description],'?' }} but what to use  instead '?' here

Comment: I mean something like this, `{{ Form::select('state[]', ['L'=>'Large', 'Small' => 'Small'], 'Small') }}`

Comment: I use foreach loop so instead 'Small' I have some value for each iterration